# How to start a systemd service as a non-root user?

Tags: pi-3, script, systemd-startup

I've been using qbittorrent-nox on a headless Raspberry Pi 3 B+. The setup was a breeze. But then I wanted to autostart qbittorrent after boot, so I wrote a systemd service unit and enabled it. It worked and the service started on boot. But it was started with root previleges. Is there any way to do this as another non-root user?

Comment: You can specify the directives `User=` and `Group=` in the `[Service]` section of the unit file. - as found using google

Comment: @Jaromanda You should post that below as an answer so the OP can mark this as resolved (and you can claim some rep, too)

Comment: @JaromandaX Wow, that was simple. Silly of me.

Comment: Look at `man systemd.exec`.

Answer (score 3):

You can include

`[Service]
...
User=pi
Group=pi
...`

in your service file.